# Numpy reshape seems to output value error

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to use `reshape`

```
import numpy as np
d = np.arange(30).reshape(1,3)
```

It is not working `cannot reshape array of size 30 into shape (1,3)`

but when I tried to use

```
d = np.arange(30).reshape(-1,3) # This works
```

Why do we have to use `-1`?.

It's really confusing and I'm can't seem to figure out how reshape works. I would really appreciate if someone can help me figure out how this works. I tried docs and other posts in `SO` but it wasn't much helpful.

I am new to ML and Python.

Comment: How would you fit 30 elements in a 1x3 array?

Comment: What do you anticipate `reshape(1, 3)` to do? There is not enough space for 30 values

Comment: Try `print(np.full((1, 3), 1))`. That's the structure you were trying to reshape to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reshape means that you order your elements of the array, according to other dimensions. For example `arange(27)` will produce a vector containing 27 elements. But with `.reshape(9, 3)` you specify here that you want to transform it into a two dimensional array, where the first dimension contains 9 elements, and the second three elements. So the result will look like:

```
>>> np.arange(27).reshape(9, 3)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

But we can also make it a 3×3×3 array:

```
>>> np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

`-1` is used as a value that will numpy derive the dimension.

So if you have an array containing 30 elements, and you reshape these to *m×3*, then *m* is 10. `-1` is thus not the real value, it is used for programmer convenience if for example you do not know the number of elements, but know that it is divisable by three.

The following two are (under the assumption that `m` contains 30 elements equivalent:

```
m.reshape(10, 3)
m.reshape(-1, 3)
```

Note that you can specify *at most* one `-1`, since otherwise there are multiple possibilities, and it becomes also harder to find a valid configuration.

Comment: so when we use `-1` it automatically finds that unknown dimension?

Comment: @user2475: indeed. So `-1` as a dimension makes of course no sense: a dimension can not contain -1 elements.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful. :)